# Youtube video not showing in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

I am very ignorant in this area. I wanted to embed a video in my website. I just went on w3schools and copy-pasted the example code.

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=1">
</iframe>
```

Why does the video than not show in the website? I am using Google Chrome.

EDIT:

The problem was that I was using the real youtube address instead the URL for embedding.

Comment: look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223028/google-chrome-wont-allow-iframe-to-load-an-html-file

Comment: Glad you fixed it, but please add [SOLVED] to the title.

Comment: @NicholasJohnson the OP shouldn't add [SOLVED] to the title, they should post an answer so that it may help other users.

Answer (score 0):

it's actually works perfectly, checkout the other code, may be the iframe is hidden by any other controls [image]